What does methenoel mean?
In episode 7 of Demon Lord 2099, the protagonist defeats his foe by dissolving him in some sort of magical battery acid. The Demon Lord declares to the dead soul, "Marcus, let us meet again after your methenoel" (English sub on Crunchyroll).  Fine and dandy, at least the awful dragon CGI was ending.  But what the heck does "methenoel" mean?

Mis-spelling of "methanol", perhaps?

"Methenoel" is a reincarnation magic (official name) / resurrection ceremony (alternative name).
"Methenoel" was first mentioned in episode 1, around 5:40, when Veltol was resurrected after 500 years, and then he told Machina that she had successfully completed the resurrection ceremony.
The process is explained more in detail in chapter 1 of the light novel.

His return had only been possible through the power of Methenoel, a type of reincarnation magic Veltol himself had created to tie his memories and physical form together with his soul, then convert that into data and send it to the future. The aether used that data to emulate his body and rebuild it.
[...]
It was, of course, the first time he’d ever used Methenoel. Although he had figured out the logic and completed the technic, he’d had no opportunity to test it out.
[...]
“No matter. You saw to my revival and completion of Methenoel, and for that, I commend you.”
“Such is my duty as your vassal, Lord Veltol. Your praise is wasted on me.”
There were a few requirements for restoring a soul via Methenoel. There had to be a caster to activate it at the proper place and time. Methenoel, a ritual spell, couldn’t be performed alone. One person had to cast it on their soul while another resurrected that soul.

Official Yen Press translation

Thank you; I appreciate the detailed response.

Did you notice the tribute to 1982 Blade Runner in the first episode?
